# create a nuget package with dll in c# and c++

Tags: nuget, interop, wrapper, nuget-package, nuget-package-explorer

In my C# project I use purely C# dll, but for some functions it is possible to use only C++ libraries and dlls.
What I am trying to do is create a Nuget package consisting of C# dll and C++ dll.
Using Nuget Package Explorer and following the procedure for creating a Nuget package, I placed the C# dll in the "lib" folder and the C++ library in the "content" folder.
Created the Nuget package, I tried to import it into my project, but after building, in the output path there is only my dll in C#.
What should I do to be able to import the dll in cpp into the output of my project?

Comment: Here's a nuget docs issue with links to many other similar questions. You can try reading these and see what solutions other people have posted to try to figure it out: https://github.com/NuGet/learn.microsoft.com-nuget/issues/2070